# How to use dynamically generated function parameter name in R function?

Tags: r, function, generics, parameters

I'm using a function/object method which accepts any parameter (...). However, i want to run this function with dynamically generated parameter names, or with variables that contain the name. So this would look something like:

```
parametername <- paste0("Parameter", "1")
value <- 3.4
genericFunction(parameterName = value)
```

Where parameterName should be replaced by the actual textstring to name the parameter. Which does not happen (it just names each parameter 'parameterName'). I know for named lists you can use setNames or double square brackets:

```
genericList[[parametername = value]]
```

However, this does not work with function parameter slots. Is there any way how I could get this to work?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `do.call()`.  The `args` argument can be a named list, so build a list like `args <- list(value); names(args) <- parametername` then call it as `do.call(genericFunction, args)`.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment! I see this does work for a function, but it gives an error when using an object method. As a workaround, I wrote my own object/method to get it done. Might be a bit overkill, but I didn't have too much time to fix the problem. Thanks again!

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer to the problem.  It sounds interesting!